# How to compare a text with ITEMS inside a list box in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
 string EmailDomain = useremail.Split('@')[1].Trim();
                foreach (ListItem li in lst_DomainList.Items)
                {
                    if (EmailDomain.Equals(li))
                    {
                    }
                 }
```

If the input is `abc@email.com` then after split the EmailDomain value is email.com 
the value inside the list  are

```
email
email.com
```

Here the second items in the list matches with the EmailDomain value,. but the way I have done it it says they dont match, what should I do

Comment: Try using `EmailDomain.Equals(li.value)`

Comment: Please don't use the `asp` tag (it's right there in the text for the tag).

Answer (score 4):

You're comparing the string with the `ListItem` itself. You probably want to compare with `li.Value` or `li.Text`...

```
string domain = userEmail.Split('@')[1].Trim();
foreach (ListItem li in lst_DomainList.Items)
{
    if (li.Value == domain)
    {
        ...
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

`ListItem li` refers to the actual item in the list box.  You should compare against `li.Text`

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be:

```
if (EmailDomain.Equals(li.Text))
```